# strcpy misalignment __strcpy_sse2_unaligned()

Tags: c, strcpy

What should be the correct approach(es) to solve `__strcpy_sse2_unaligned()` problems?
ie. `strcpy(enc_buf, base64_encode(buf));` leads to `__strcpy_sse2_unaligned()` in gdb
So what are the precautionary measures to prevent such things?

Comment: Prevent _what_, exactly?

Comment: @black I meant to say what should we do to solve misalignment problem as given in gdb output

Comment: Why is it a _problem_ that you find yourself in `__strcpy_sse2_unaligned` in gdb? What exactly would you like to prevent?

Comment: Till now I have never done specific anything for this. It never gives problem to me. You can assume too much C coding I have done.

Comment: Are you asking why the compiler generates `__strcpy_sse2_unaligned` rather than, say, `__strcpy_sse2_aligned`?

Comment: @zwol a code got core dump and strcpy is crashing. so why this unaligned problem came. as I read this is due to misalignment of data in words. So what is the approach we should take to prevent this.

Comment: No, the crash is not due to misalignment.  Use [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) to find the true bug.

Comment: @black code is crashing due to strcpy. so I wanted to know is there any solution for nonalignment issues

Comment: Is the problem due to `base64_encode(buf)` or `strcpy(enc_buf, ...);` or the alignments of `buf, end_buf`?  I think it may be the first.

Comment: @black I don't have the code, i just have the core dump and the snippet where crashing.

Comment: I should explain that `strcpy` is _required_ not to crash due to alignment issues, because `char`s do not need to be aligned.  The crash happens to have happened inside a function with `unaligned` in its name, but that doesn't mean anything interesting.  The bug is probably either that `enc_buf` is an invalid pointer or `base64_encode` is returning an invalid pointer.  Again, `valgrind` will tell you what's really going on.

Comment: if it crashes, buf may not have a NUL ending character.  It could be also base64_encode() returns without a NUL ending character.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is unable to determine whether your source and destination `char*` are aligned (usually word or even quad-word aligned) and therefore is backing up to the unaligned yet possibly optimized `strcpy` routine. You'd need to explicitly hint about the missed guess it is doing; otherwise, it'll just give up: unaligned access is often disallowed for SSE or still very slow.

**But**, if you're getting a segfault it is very unlikely it's a library issue (it's a *largely* used function) and it just cannot be due to misalignment. It's much likely your code exhibits undefined behavior somewhere, due to buffer overrun, for example. Check your pointers with `valgrind` or `-fsanitize=address`.